# Gradle Task test failing due java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle

I am migrating Spring Boot Project from Gradle 7.3 to 8.1
During Gradle test task, all the test cases about 71/74 are failing with same reason, which were working fine earlier.

```
com.X.Y.Z.A.methodName > testCaseName FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770
            Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at KafkaServer.scala:308
                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at BuiltinClassLoader.java:641
```

In build.gradle

I am using org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:3.0.7

If anyone needs more detail, do let me know.

Comment: The full stack trace of the failure would be useful as it should show the name of the class that could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was due to mismatch in version of Spring Kafka and Spring FW. Its now fixed.